# Unable to load resource due to SSL certificates using Selenium Webdriver with BrowserMob proxy to capture har file

Tags: ssl, https, selenium-webdriver, proxy-server, har

I'm using Selenium Webdriver (Chromedriver) in Java, along with BrowserMob Proxy Server to capture HTTP traffic in a har file. I recently encountered a problem where sections of the website would not load, and I've narrowed it down to this error:
"Failed to load resource https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js".

It seems that when using the proxy server, the Selenium driver can't access the SSL certificate for the https link. Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(4040);
server.start();
Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
server.newHar("myHar");
Har har = server.getHar();
server.stop();
```

I have tried adding `"capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);"` and this solves the above problem, but only if I delete `"capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);"` and then I am no longer able to capture the har file.

I tried switching to a firefox driver and setting up a firefox profile, but either I am not doing it properly or it won't work for my purposes either.

I have also tried setting up the cybervillainsCA certificate  that comes with BrowserMob proxy in Trusted Root Certifaction Authorities, but that hasn't solved the issue either.

Does anyone know how to solve this in a way that I can collect HTTP traffic as well as successfully load the resource mentioned above?

Comment: it may me a duplicate question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682868/how-can-i-intercept-ssl-requests-with-browsermob-proxy/19862030#19862030)

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was scrapping the proxy entirely, and instead switched to using a Firefox profile with the Firebug and NetExport extensions in order to export the har file. This ended up significantly slowing down the tests, and exports a har for each page visited rather than for the entire session.

Code:
`//Firefox profile`
`FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();`
`ffProfile.addExtension(new File("firebug-1.11.4-fx.xpi"));`
`ffProfile.addExtension(new File("netExport-0.9b3.xpi"));`

`//Set default Firefox preferences`
`ffProfile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);` 
`String domain = "extensions.firebug.";`

`//Set default Firebug preferences`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "currentVersion", "1.11.4");`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "allPagesActivation", "on");`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "defaultPanelName", "net");`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "net.enableSites", true);`

`//Set default NetExport preferences` 
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "netexport.autoExportToFile", true);`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "netexport.showPreview", false);`
`ffProfile.setPreference(domain + "netexport.defaultLogDir", "string file path");`

`//WebDriver, instantiated outside the method`
`driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);`
`s = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.google.ca/");`

I collected the har file after each page as follows:

`HarFileReader r = new HarFileReader();`
`HarFileWriter w = new HarFileWriter();`
`int count = 1;`
`String allHars = "";`
`String harFolderPath = "file path for har";`
`File dir = new File(harFolderPath);`
`for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {`
`HarLog log = r.readHarFile(child);`
`File f = new File(harFolderPath + "\\test"+count+".txt");`
`w.writeHarFile(log, f);`
`allHars = allHars + readFileAsString(f.getPath());`
`count++;`
`}`
`FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);`