# How can I intercept SSL requests with BrowserMob proxy

Tags: ssl, selenium, proxy, browsermob

I am using BrowserMob proxy 2.0-beta-8 in a test automation project with Selenium. The page I'm testing against is using https and I need to rewrite the user agent header. For plain http requests everything works fine - the request interceptor is called and I can rewrite the header. However, for https requests the interceptor is not called at all.

Does BrowserMob currently not support intercepting https requests or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what browser are you using:

1) If you are using Firefox/Chrome, Selenium2 and BrowserMob >=2.0-beta8 then everything should work out of the box

2) If you are using other browser, [check how to install browser CA certificate](http://blog.mogotest.com/2013/03/05/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium2/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. We are using Firefox and have installed the certificate but the proxy still does not get the request. Any ideas? Should this be working?